# Upgrade cakephp 3.10 to cakephp 4 throws Hash::insert() error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

Following all the migration steps from the CakePHP manual, I end up with a error 500 on all pages.
The log tells me this:

```
> [Wed Jul 19 11:56:02.566953 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 12776]
> [client 178.117.91.131:57762] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP
> Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
> Cake\\Utility\\Hash::insert() must be of the type string, int given,
> called in
> /var/www/clients/client0/web4/web/ID/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Core/Configure.php
> on line 92 and defined in
> /var/www/clients/client0/web4/web/ID/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Utility/Hash.php:316\nStack
> trace:\n#0
> /var/www/clients/client0/web4/web/ID/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Core/Configure.php(92):
> Cake\\Utility\\Hash::insert()\n#1
> /var/www/clients/client0/web4/web/ID/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Core/Configure.php(339):
> Cake\\Core\\Configure::write()\n#2
> /var/www/clients/client0/web4/web/ID/config/bootstrap.php(74):
> Cake\\Core\\Configure::load()\n#3
> /var/www/clients/client0/web4/web/ID/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/BaseApplication.php(161):
> require_once('/var/www/client...')\n#4
> /var/www/clients/client0/web4/web/ID/src/Application.php(41):
> Cake\\Http\\BaseApplication->bootstrap()\n#5
> /var/www/clients/client0/web4/web/ID/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Server.php(10...'
```

Since I don't know - or cannot see - where the hash is called in Application.php or bootstrap.php, I'm not sure how to debug this.

Comment: The line numbers tell you where the calls happen (note that it's a stack trace showing you the flow of execution through which the code went to get to the call. So the actual call that went wrong will only be in the top entry in the stack trace, I'd expect. But you can always do a Find to locate it too

Comment: Also, please provide a link to the guide you followed, and tell us what version of PHP you're running this on.

Answer (score 0):

php is getting more and more strict. It is not a CakePHP issue. Your issue is based on passing an integer to a function which doesn't accept an integer anymore. Often these issues can be solved by converting to string by using `(string)` like:

```
$path = 3;
$values = 'your value';
Hash::insert($data, (string)$path, $values);
```

But in your case the actual issue is in your bootstrap.php on line 74 where you call `Configure::load()` which calls `Configure::write()` which then calls `Hash::insert()` therefore every key in your config (usually in `config/app.php`) must be of type string -> somewhere in your config you must have integer keys or implicit integer keys by skipping the key (numeric array):

```
$config = [
    ['3' => 'your value'], // doesn't work because the actual key would be an automatic numeric array index (0 in this case)
    '3' => 'your value', // works
     (string)3 => 'your value', // works
     4 => 'your value', // doesn't work without warnings or errors
    '5' => ['3' => 'your value'], // works 
    '6' => [3 => 'your value'], // works (numeric array as value on second level) 
];

Configure::write($config);
```